# Embeding SWF with swfobject in IE show blank page

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, swfobject

I'm loading swf files in my website with swfobject. Everything worked fine but since I installed Flash version 14, in IE I got a blank page where my swf file was supposed to be. In Chrome and Firefox everything is OK but in IE (8,9,10 and 11) I got this problem.

This is how I load the swf:

```
var flashvars = {
    viewlog: "0",
    wsurl: "WebServices/DynamicComposition.asmx?WSDL",
    colorSelected: "0x0066FF",
    colorBlocked: "0xEDBF3F",
    colorPending: "0xBEE1BE",
    colorNotSolved: "0xcccccc",
    colorAdded: "0xFF7D7D",
    fontfamily: "Tahoma",
    fontSize: "11",
    viewBoundingBox: "0",
    viewPending: "1",
    viewHighPriorityParts: "0",
    hideLowPriority: "1",
    zoomMore_tooltip: "Zoom (Aumentar)",
    zoomLess_tooltip: "Zoom (Disminuir)",
    zoomAdjust_tooltip: "Mostrar imagen a tamaño completo",
    print_tooltip: "Imprimir",
    lowPriority_tooltip: "Mostrar piezas con baja prioridad",
    viewPending_tooltip: "Mostrar piezas no visibles",
    hidePending_tooltip: "Ocultar piezas no visibles",
    lateralityRight_tooltip: "Bloquear lado derecho",
    lateralityLeft_tooltip: "Bloquear lado izquierdo",
    lateralityLock_tooltip: "Eliminar bloqueo lateral",
    checkBinaryData: "1",
    fontSizeHeaderPrint: "11",
    fontSizeFooterPrint: "7",
    gradientType: "linear",
    gradientRatio1: "0",
    gradientRatio2: "210"
};

var params = {
    movie: "flash/Main.swf",
    bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
    quality: "high",
    allowScriptAccess: "always",
    wmode: "transparent"
};
var attributes = {
    id: "CD",
    name: "CD"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("flash/Main.swf", "capaComposicion", "98%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, swfCallback);
```

This is the container where it's supposed to be load

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCD" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
    <div id="capaComposicion"></div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And this is the swfCallback function, but event.success is empty when it is supposed to be true or false.

```
function swfCallback( event ) {
    alert("flash object is created:", event.success );
}
```

I'm missing something? What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you helping a desperate man :D

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in this question, I found out that the problem is that sometimes flashvars are not send properly the first time you call your swf. You need to refresh your page and after that swf is loaded properly with the values I send.

Now I need to figure out how to ensure that swf receives the flashvars I send. Using a preloader maybe?